# select only max values per group sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table

```
Sales Key Cod  Value
10    A   109  10.99  
7     A   10   11.05
3     B   1    10.30
25    B   125  15.30
```

How can I get only the max(sales) value per key, like:

```
Sales Key Cod  Value
10    A   109  10.99  
25    B   125  15.30
```

I tried:

```sql
SELECT MAX(sales), key, cod, value FROM table GROUP BY key
```

But i got the following error

```
expression 'cod' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function
```

When I put cod in group by, then I got the two values, not only the max.

I know I can solve this problem using Window Function, but I think it's not the efficient way to solve this. Any thoughs on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using a window function. But if you dislike that, you can also just use a subquery to avoid your `GROUP BY` issue:

```
SELECT 
sales,
column1,
cod,
column2
FROM yourtable y1
WHERE sales =
(SELECT MAX(y2.sales)
FROM yourtable y2
WHERE y1.column1 = y2.column1)
ORDER BY column1;
```

Note: Renamed your columns "key" and "value" in my query to "column1" and "column2" because SQL key words should not be used as column name or table name.